# How to debug EntityMalformedException?

Tags: entities, debugging

I've got fatal error *EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7700 of .\includes\common.inc)* **when trying to access user/xyz**.

I tried to retrieve info about the malformed node at line 7700, where the error message is built, thinks like :

```
if (!isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']}) || $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']} === '') {
 dpm($info);// or dpm($entity);
 throw new EntityMalformedException(t('Missing bundle property on entity of type @entity_type.', array('@entity_type' => $entity_type)));
}
```

`dpm($entity)` returns an unexpected user object, and $info a huge qty of things.

Could somebody put me on the right way ?

I already read whatever I could find about *Missing bundle property* errors, but none helped solving.

`dpm($entity)` returns

```
uid (String, 2 characters ) 70
name (String, 9 characters ) John
pass (String, 55 characters ) $S$DUwPuOuDPiDL4nRTYXqc7a5uOfMKey7pyhOFUEKka1XM...
mail (String, 30 characters ) john@example.com
theme (String, 0 characters )
signature (String, 0 characters )
signature_format (String, 13 characters ) filtered_html
created (String, 10 characters ) 1396286331
access (String, 10 characters ) 1397146661
login (String, 10 characters ) 1396513460
status (String, 1 characters ) 1
timezone (NULL)
language (String, 2 characters ) fr
picture (NULL)
init (String, 30 characters ) john@example.com
data (Array, 5 elements)
roles (Array, 1 element)
og_user_node (Array, 0 elements)
message_subscribe_email (Array, 1 element)
field_bio (Array, 0 elements)
field_name_first (Array, 1 element)
field_name_last (Array, 1 element)
field_facebook_url (Array, 0 elements)
field_linkedin_url (Array, 0 elements)
field_twitter_url (Array, 0 elements)
user_trusted_contacts (Array, 1 element)
group_group (Array, 1 element)
group_access (Array, 1 element)
metatags (Array, 0 elements)
rdf_mapping (Array, 3 elements)
realname (String, 13 characters ) John Doe
content (Array, 13 elements)
entity_view_prepared (Boolean) TRUE
privatemsg_disabled (Boolean) FALSE
```

Comment: This is usually a pretty low level one that you can find out just by dpm()'ing the $entity. Make sure you are passing the entity itself -- and not a set of entities that entity load functions return.

Comment: tks Ayesh ! sorry not sure I understood? As I dmp() exactly at the test point, and it returns only one entity, it should be the one who causes error ? maybe all my users are malformed ? on the other hand it says of type node, not user.. what do you mean by pretty low level please ?

Comment: I meant the it is basically checking if the bundle information exist before throwing the exception.
If you could post the output of dpm($entity) (with the sensitive information blurred of course), that will help others to see what's wrong.

Comment: Tks. If I only knew which is the sensitive info... :( About the check, this is where I placed the dpm I believe.

Comment: @Kojo The cause is actually a really simple one...something is calling `entity_extract_ids('node', $var);`, but instead of a node object for `$var`, it's passing a user object. If you have any custom or dev version contrib modules, try disabling them one by one to see it you can find the culprit

Comment: Tks Clive ! wow I'll try to find, but this is like looking for a needle in a hay stack... because this is an advanced project based on commons + commerce + several custom modules :(

Comment: Yikes. `dpm(debug_print_backtrace());` will be invaluable here. You can see what module started it all off by following the functions back to the beginning of the request

Comment: BTW I prefer the French version of that saying ;)

Comment: haha  "chercher une aiguille dans une botte de foin !" ;) I'll learn how to use dpm(debug_print_backtrace()) and turn back let's say in a weeeeek. Many thanks for your help

Comment: No worries, if you can get xdebug installed and configured with `xdebug.collect_params = 4` that will also make your life a lot easier

Comment: @Clive : I found the needle, thanks again for advices !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Clive comments, I solved the issue as following.

Added `ddebug_backtrace()` where error occured (*entity_extract_ids(), line 7700 of .\includes\common.inc* ) to print the function call stack.

Then looking for anything unexpected in output, I found that a **pane visibility rule** might be the problem.

```
19: ctools_entity_field_value_ctools_access_check() (Array, 2 elements)
  file (String, 81 characters ) profiles\commons\modules\contrib\ctools\plugins...
  $...['19: ctools_entity_field_value_ctools_access_check()']['file']
    profiles\commons\modules\contrib\ctools\plugins\access\entity_field_value.inc:213
  args (Array, 3 elements)
    0 (Array, 2 elements)
      field_theme (Array, 1 element)
      //...
```

I had applied a patch on `entity_field_value.inc` a few days ago just [to solve a visibility rule notice](https://drupal.org/node/1630820#comment-8710763)... and created a test visibility rule with a field_theme condition.

Now reverting patch or removing any pane visibility rule solved current EntityMalformedException bug... Powerful `ddebug_backtrace()` !

Comment: I tried this method and i got 1000's of line of code on front end. How do you see where the error is?

Comment: @Sam have a look at Kenorb answer, it might help you

Answer (score 37):

The error:

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node.

happens, because your bundle property is malformed either on load or save, so Drupal can't find what type of bundle is it.

The logic of that Exception is:

```
// Explicitly fail for malformed entities missing the bundle property.
if (!isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']}) || $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']} === '') {
  // var_dump(debug_backtrace()); exit; // You may want this line to debug.
  throw new EntityMalformedException(t('Missing bundle property on entity of type @entity_type.', array('@entity_type' => $entity_type)));
}
```

So basically value of `$info['entity keys']['bundle']` (for node it's: `type`) can't be found in `$entity` object (`$node->type` for the node), therefore Drupal doesn't know with what kind of entity it's dealing with. So most likely your entity is invalid (e.g. you're loading something else instead) or it is just empty (`$entity` is `NULL`).

---

If you haven't modified any Drupal code, this potentially can be caused by variety of things (most likely by specific Drupal module bug), such as:

- [saving invalid entity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10756618/55075) such as:

  - missing `type` from the node object (e.g. wrongly generated by Devel Generate?);
- [orphaned nodes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572#comment-6891428) in node table;
- [invalid rows in field_data_field_xxx table](https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572#comment-7002730);
- having orphaned nodes, caused by:

  - [search view having indexed nodes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572#comment-7256200) which aren't in the system;
  - other modules (like [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572#comment-9314595)) removing nodes from Drupal improperly;
- nodes having invalid/non-existing references; for term data this can be checked by:

  ```
  drush sqlq "SELECT nid, title from node WHERE nid IN (select entity_id from  field_data_field_some_ref WHERE field_some_ref_tid not IN (select tid from taxonomy_term_data));"
  ```

  Where `field_data_field_some_ref` is data field of `field_some_ref` which is type of 'Term reference'.

  See: [DB records not deleted for Term Reference Fields after Term is Deleted](https://www.drupal.org/node/1281114)
- having orphaned taxonomy terms (so you may use [Taxonomy Orphanage](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_orphanage));
- [entity caching issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/94720/1908);
- when using [Rules Link module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1888610);
- invalid custom code (human error) such as:

  - [badly implemented Entity API](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/106851/1908),
  - [badly implemented CTools/Form API](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/100987/1908),
  - `!empty()` test on the entity variable before calling `field_get_items()`,
  - [rendering field by invalid calls](https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572#comment-8901361),
  - triggering functions which shouldn't be triggered on certain pages (e.g. [field_view_field()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572#comment-10302165)),

Here is the responsible code which is thrown by Drupal core (file: `common.inc`):

```
 if (!empty($info['entity keys']['bundle'])) {
    // Explicitly fail for malformed entities missing the bundle property.
    if (!isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']}) || $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']} === '') {
      throw new EntityMalformedException(t('Missing bundle property on entity of type @entity_type.', array('@entity_type' => $entity_type)));
    }
    $bundle = $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']};
  }
```

---

#### Debugging

If you don't recognise anything above, the easiest thing to debug that kind of error is by placing `var_dump(debug_backtrace());` or `dd(debug_backtrace());` (when Devel is on) before the actual `throw new EntityMalformedException` on the affected line in `common.inc`.

<sup>Note: Using `dd()` function from Devel will generate the debugging info to the file in your [Drupal temp folder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/30113/1908) (`temporary://drupal_debug.txt`) with backtrace dump, otherwise could be too big and difficult to read when dumping on the screen. When using `var_dump()`, it's easier to call `die();` after the call and check the dump in the view-source mode of the page.</sup>

If this is happening on node save, check this [EntityMalformedException post at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10756618/55075) for more detailed instructions.

---

See also the following Drupal issue: [#1778572](https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572) for more ideas.

Comment: kudos for a such detailed answer! I solved my issue a long time ago, but not doubt this will be helpful for a lot of people, me included.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! Deserves more upvotes.

Comment: I added `dd(debug_backtrace());` to the affected line in front of `throw new EntityMalformedException`, made sure Devel is enabled and ran the drush command in cron that is throwing this error and am not getting any debugging output. What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Found it: the command created a file called `drupal_debug.txt` inside `/tmp/drupal_theme/` where "drupal_theme" is the name of the drupal theme. Thanks for your excellent debugging help!

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes up when there are orphaned nodes, simply get rid of them and cron will run without any error. Search indexing will finally get to 100%. 
Backup your database before proceeding.

Assuming you have access to phpMyAdmin, run this SQL code to identify the nodes then delete them. Replace my **question** content type machine name with your specific content type machine name one after the other till you get no result, that's after deleting.

`SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.vid, nr.vid FROM drcm_node n LEFT JOIN drcm_node_revision nr ON nr.nid = n.nid WHERE n.type = 'question' AND nr.vid IS NULL ORDER BY n.nid ASC`

You can delete the orphaned nodes by using the SQL code below. Replace the numbers in the bracket with your specific node IDs

`DELETE from node where nid IN (12779,12780,12781,12782)`