# Error when non-admin user attempts to create content

Tags: entities

I have given authenticated users permission to create content but when linked to that page form a non-admin user, no fields are displayed and Drupal spits the following error:

"EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7818 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nexuswipe/includes/common.inc)."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug EntityMalformedException?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111610/how-to-debug-entitymalformedexception)

Comment: @ShawnConn since this issue is related to user roles I don't think its duplicate

Comment: Have you followed some of the troubleshooting suggestions in the post? The Devel module & `ddebug_backtrace()` should help you find where in execution this is happening. If I had to guess, some permission that *auth users don't have*, but *admin users do* is probably what's causing this issue.

Comment: Do you use  code, module or form default to creat form for authenticated users creat content?