# How do I begin to debug an EntityMetadataWrapperException error on searches?

Tags: 7, entities, search

When trying to run a `drush cron` on a Drupal 7.54 site, I see the following error.

```
$ drush cron
```

> WD cron: EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be
>   sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at node(): .
>   in          [error] EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 756 of
>   /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
>   Cron run successful.

A similar error occurs in WatchDog  when we try to search on any term:

```
$ drush wd-show --tail
```

> 641742  15/Feb 15:47  notice  search  Searched Content for test.
>   641743  15/Feb 15:47  error  php   EntityMetadataWrapperException:
>   Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type
>   and format. Value at node(): . in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 756
>   of /var/www/html/

How do I begin to even understand how to investigate such an error? This [seems to be an issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/entity?text=Invalid%20data%20value%20given&status=All) for a few other people too.

*Misc:*
In this instance of D7.54, we have enabled: Entity Reference ([entityreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)) 7.x-1.2, Entity API ([entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity)) 7.x-1.8, and - Entity tokens (entity_token) 7.x-1.8. We also running on RHEL 7.2 with PHP 5.4.16.

*What I've tried so far:*
I have commented out this section of code (using a development copy):

```
<?php
/**
       * Overridden to support setting the entity by either the object or the id.
       */
  public function set($value) {

    if (!$this->validate($value)) {
       /*throw new EntityMetadataWrapperException(t('Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at !location: !value.', array(
        // An exception's message is output through check_plain().
        '!value' => is_array($value) || is_object($value) ? var_export($value) : $value,
        '!location' => $this->debugIdentifierLocation(),
      )));*/
    }
```

But this is obviously not a sustainable exercise. It does seem to at least produce the results.

> [image]

**Question:**
Short of changing the module code myself -- not a great option -- what other options could I employ? Is there a way to rescue search page without directly editing this module?

**Update**: So this works if I allow searches only on users. The error is thrown when Content is searched.

Comment: You could use the php function [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). Print its content either to the screen or to the watchdog log: `watchdog('my debug', print_r(debug_backtrace(), TRUE));`. Add such a line to `entity.wrapper.inc` right before line 756 and it should give you the chain of all calling functions and parameters. If the page crashes, you can use debug_backtrace's limit paramter to cut the output.

Comment: Have a look at @kenorb answer to a similar question I asked sometimes ago. Really detailed and useful : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111610/how-to-debug-entitymalformedexception