# PHP error in the log after PHP and Drupal upgrade

Tags: views, 8

I got this error message in the log but not sure what is it about and how to fix it.  Has anyone seen the same issue before and know how to fix it?  Thank you so much!

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityMalformedException: The "view" entity cannot have a URI as it does not have an ID in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->toUrl() (line 192 of /var/www/drupal_dev_8.8.6/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityBase.php)

Comment: Could this Issue be relevant: [After updating to Drupal 8.8.0 I get 1 error has been found: Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/yoast_seo/issues/3110455)?

Comment: you may find this useful : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111610/how-to-debug-entitymalformedexception

Comment: Thank you for your responses but I think these are different than the issue I am having.  The error message I see on the screen when the page load are:: Bootstrap Accordion style will not display without the "Panel title" setting. and Plugin ID 'default' was not found.

Comment: @Silvia did you update the DB tables by running `/update.php` after doing the upgrade?

Comment: Hi! Sorry about my delay in responding! No I don't think we did that.  Is that something we need to do?  Thank you!